# Laravel 4.1 Route::controller inside a name spaced route group does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

It seems that adding

```
Route::controller('acme','Acme');
```

inside a name spaced route group does not work and i have to take it out of the whole group

check the code below

```
// this code does not work, error message:
//
// --------------------
// ReflectionException
// Class Api\Controllers\V1\Api\Controllers\V1\Acme does not exist
// --------------------
//
// the error appears after adding Route::controller('acme', 'Acme'); inside the name spaced route group

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api','namespace' => 'Api\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1','namespace' => 'V1'], function()
    {
        Route::resource('acme', 'Acme', [ 'only' => ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'] ]);

        Route::controller('acme', 'Acme');
    });
});




// this code is working fine after taking Route::controller('acme', 'Acme'); outside the name spaced route group

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api','namespace' => 'Api\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1','namespace' => 'V1'], function()
    {
        Route::resource('acme', 'Acme', [ 'only' => ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy'] ]); 
    });
});

Route::controller('acme', 'Api\Controllers\V1\Acme');
```

you can view the code here if you prefer it more readable

http://paste.laravel.com/1inX

is it a bug or am i missing some thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. Just reproduced it here to confirm.

And posted this issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3084

**UPDATE**

It works now, Taylor just killed that bug.